# Looking to update a table based on responses to a google form

Tags: google-apps-script

Good Day!
I am looking to add a script to the doc linked here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q26G0C7tknmYlUXBQHw9zPwXtnQtgWY2XkiYoqPFoPI/edit?usp=sharing

I am looking to get a script to update the 'Supply totals' page based on four variables. I have a table set in supply totals based on a location and Material type. My goal for the script is to have the script update said table for each response(from a google form), where the script checks for storage location, then checks the material type, pulls the amount previously listed, then adds or subtracts the 'crates submitted' response, per the form.
I have limited knowledge of Java, and have tried and understand the get update portions, but the other pieces actually confuse me.

If you have an example code to show, the more explanation in the code would be awesome, I would love to learn said code!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

G'Day, mate! ) Basically it could be something like this:

```
// the cols and rows objects can be created dynamically of course

var cols = {
  'Silk Farms'    : 3,
  'Mercy\'s Wail' : 4,
  'TEST'          : 5,
  'Land Mine'     : 6
}

var rows = {
  'B-mats'            :  6,
  'R-mats'            :  7,
  'E-mats'            :  8,
  'HE-mats'           :  9,
  'Diesel'            : 10,
  'Petrol'            : 11,
  'Prototype Kits'    : 12,
  'Soldier Supplies'  : 13,
  'Garrison Supplies' : 14,
  'Bunker Supplies'   : 15,
  'Relic Materials'   : 16
}


function transfer_data() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // get data from last row of the source sheet 'Stockpile Subs'
  var src_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Stockpile Subs');
  var last_row = src_sheet.getLastRow()
  var data = src_sheet.getRange(last_row,3,1,6).getValues().flat();
  var change   = data[0];
  var location = data[1];
  var material = data[2];
  var amount   = data[3];
  amount = (change == 'Subtracting') ? -amount : amount;

  // set the data into the cell on the destination sheet 'Supply Totals'
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Supply Totals');
  var dest_cell = dest_sheet.getRange(rows[material],cols[location]);
  var value = dest_cell.getValue();
  dest_cell.setValue(value + amount);
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------

// this function should be run just once to install the trigger
function install_onFormSubmitTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('transfer_data')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onFormSubmit().create();
}

// to delete all installed triggers
function delete_all_triggers() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
}
```

The function `function transfer_data()` should work if there is correct data on the sheet 'Stockpile Subs'. All the names in cells should look exactly like they are in script: 'TEST', not 'Test' of 'test'; 'Mersy's Wail', not 'Mersys Wail'; 'B-mats', not 'b-mats' or 'Bmats', etc.

It will take the last row from the sheet 'Stockpile Subs' and put it on the sheet 'Supply Totals' when you run it manually from Editor Script.

If you want to run if automatically when you submit your form you need to install the trigger with the function `install_onFormSubmitTrigger()`. It's need to run just once from Script Editor.

I didn't test how it works with a form since I have no idea how your form looks like. It's up to you to debug it.

The `cols` and `rows` objects can be created dynamically from the table on the sheet 'Supply Totals'. But I made them static so as not to complicate the code. You can figure out by yourself how it can be done or to leave these objects static (you'll need to add more rows of course).

Comment: Thank you so much man! this was extremely helpful!